# Deploying Rails on Staging and Production using Capistrano 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, staging

i have a rails app developed with `4.2.6` and `ruby 2.2.4`. Its my application so I am the only one responsible for the development, testing and deployment.Now I have **few questions related to deployment** and would appreciate if someone can help me.
I have **two separate servers on digital ocean for staging and production**.So how can i deploy my application or what should be the order of deployment when i am done with the development and testing.So..

1. i should be deploying the code on Staging(quite obvious) and then after testing successfully, **in the staging server, deploy it to the production**.Is this the way to go ahead.
2. Or deploy the code on staging and after testing, just deploy the **changes only to the production** and restart the production server.
3. Moreover, having separate git repository for both pro and staging good or how should i proceed with code maintenance.

What is the best approach.Is there something which i really need to understand or missing.Kindly help me the goodies with deployment and what suits the best?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, Yes your first assumption is correct you run you app in `development`  on your local machine then when you are satisfied you test in in a production like environment which is `staging` then if you test everything an its fine then do a final deploy to `production`.

Comment: Second you dont need to have different git repos for both you should have a main branch where everything goes when its ready for production most of the times this is called `master`....then for the feature you are working create a separate branch where the changes goes and this is the branch where you add new features to your application usually known as `develop` or the `name of the feature` or `name bug you are fixing`...capistrano will allow you to choose what branch to deploy

Comment: so afer you install capistrano it generates 2 file a `staging` and `production` file in the directory `config/deploy` customize this individually place the `ip or endpoin/url` of staging server in staging and for production server in`  production`

Comment: added the above as an answer for anyone who might be wondering about the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, Yes your first assumption is correct you run you app in `development` on your local machine then when you are satisfied you test in in a `production like` environment which is `staging` then if you test everything an its fine then do a final deploy to `production` where its ready to be accessed by your users.

Second you dont need to have different git repos for both you should have a main branch where everything goes when its ready for production most of the times this is called `master`....then for the feature you are working create a separate branch where the changes goes and this is the branch where you add new features to your application usually known as `develop` or `the name of the feature` or `name bug you are fixing`...capistrano will allow you to choose what branch to deploy

Third afer you install capistrano it generates 2 file a `staging` and `production` file in the directory `config/deploy` customize this individually place the `ip or endpoin/url` of staging server in `staging.rb` and for production server in`production.rb`